# Laravel DB select only/except?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this line:

```
$user = DB::table("users")
            ->where("email", $email)
            ->where("password", $password)
            ->first();
```

This selects all columns. Is there a way to discard or pick which columns to fetch or do I have to add each column I want to respond with manually? Like `Request` `only()` and `except()` methods.

Manual way:

```
response()->json([
    "name" => $user->name,
    ...
])
```

Comment: Yes, use ->select('email','password')

Comment: So instead of first() I use select(...) ?

Comment: no you add select as a function on the query before you get the results (with ->first() ) http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects

Comment: I have added answer...

Comment: Do you get solution? @Arbitur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get selected column....

```
$user = DB::table("users")
        ->select('name')
        ->where("email", $email)
        ->where("password", $password)
        ->first();
```

or

```
$user = DB::table("users")
        ->select('name')
        ->where("email", $email)
        ->where("password", $password)
        ->get();
```

you can return this result as json as follows

```
return Response::json($user);
```

For this you should add the controller `use Response` on the top.

Comment: Thanks, so there is only option to select which, and not which to ignore?

Comment: Actually this is the proper way to select data from the database... This similar to `SELECT` query

Comment: Yes but just wondering if I would add a column later and dont have to add that column in my source aswell. Maybe Ill have to make a custom function for that?

Comment: You will add column in future and don't want to add your source means you just `select *` from the db, then use it in view by column name. I don't know your question has solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an `array` in the `first` method with each field name you want to get.

```
->first(['field1', 'field2']);
```